# How do i solve publishing problems with visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

[image]

I have followed all the instructions to publish my application via ClickOnce
it keeps popping up the above error when I try to install on the host computer

Comment: Did you update the version number for clickonce program?

Comment: How do I do that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are using ClickOnce but I see the error is related to a file with extension (.msi), it seems that you have tried other ways to publish your application and one of that you tried is Installer Package (.msi), which should not be related to ClickOnce.

Try to put Only your Original application in a different folder and follow the steps to publish it via ClickOnce. I want you to do this because it seems to me that the error is not be related to ClickOnce nor an error related to the main application.

Wish my answer is clear if not just let me know, good luck

Comment: thank you, i just upgraded to vs 2017 and downloaded the advanced installer